# Retrieve only numbers and ignore alphabets from String

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I have strings like 10A or 20B. I want 10 in 10A or 20 in 20B. How to split only numbers from string using VBScript or QTP internal commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a regular expression:

```
s = "20B"

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^\d+"

For Each m In re.Execute(s)
  num = CInt(m)
Next

WScript.Echo num
```

Comment: Nice solution. 
Is a loop really required in this case? How about -  
`s = "20B"

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^\d+"

Set matches = re.Execute(s)
WScript.Echo CInt(matches(0).Value)`

Comment: It's not required, but it's the simplest way to also handle non-matches (i.e. situations where the string doesn't begin with a number). Your code would raise an error in those cases.